# assembly on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, assembly

how can i make a device input and output control program on windows 7??

Previously there was an option called debug where we wrote our programs. but as far as i know this feature is no more in windows 7. how can i do assembly on windows7??

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410776/Integrating-a-compiler-assembler-in-VS-Using-NASM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like you want to write a device driver? If so, download the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/wdkpkg.mspx) from Microsoft.

You can use this to write your driver in assmbly code if you wish. Be aware that this is NOT a trivial task.

What may be a better idea for you is to either install the WinXP virtual machine feature that comes with Windows7, or install WinXP/98/95 on an old machine, and do your coding on that. Under those OSes the driver model was simpler, and you could easily access the interrupts directly and/or easily elevate yourself into Ring 0 if you needed to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an assembler such as [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/), [YASM](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/), etc., or [MASM which is free](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2006/06/08/622485.aspx) with Visual Studio Express (for non-commercial use).

I was thinking of [Grdb](http://www.members.tripod.com/ladsoft/grdb.htm), but it is only available for 32-bit, as a debug alternative.

I'm not sure what you are asking for with your first question, so I cannot answer it. I hope the above answers your second question.

Answer (score 1):

Debug is available on Windows 7 32 bit, but not 64 bit.